# In Flask, what is "request.args" and how is it used?

Tags: python, flask, pagination, get, request

As a Flask beginner, I can't understand how `request.args` is used. I read somewhere that it is used to return values of query string (correct me if I'm wrong) and how many parameters `request.args.get()` takes.

I know that when I have to store submitted form data, I can use `fname = request.form.get("firstname")`. Here, only one parameter is passed, whereas the code below takes two parameters.

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    cnx = db_connect()
    cur = cnx.cursor()
    output = []

    page = request.args.get('page', 1)

    try:
        page = int(page)
        skip = (page-1)*4
    except:
        abort(404)
   
    stmt_select = "select * from posts limit %s, 4;"
    values=[skip]

    cur.execute(stmt_select,values)
    x=cur.fetchall()

    for row in reversed(x):
        data = {
           "uid":row[0],
           "pid":row[1],
           "subject":row[2],
           "post_content":row[3],
           "date":datetime.fromtimestamp(row[4]),
        }
        output.append(data)
    
    next = page + 1
    previous = page-1
    if previous<1:
    previous=1
    return render_template("home.html", persons=output, next=next, previous=previous)
```

Please explain why it takes two parameters, and then what its use is.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

According to the [`flask.Request.args`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/api/#flask.Request.args) documents.

> **flask.Request.args**
> A **MultiDict** with the parsed contents of the query string. (The part in the URL after the question mark).

So the `args.get()` is method `get()` for [`MultiDict`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/latest/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.get), whose prototype is as follows:

```
get(key, default=None, type=None)
```

---

In newer version of flask ([v1.0.x](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/api/#flask.Request.args) and [v1.1.x](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/api/#flask.Request.args)),  [`flask.Request.args`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/api/#flask.Request.args) is an [`ImmutableMultiDict`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.16.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.ImmutableMultiDict)(an immutable [`MultiDict`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.16.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict)), so the prototype and specific method above are still valid.

Comment: Things might have changed since the answer was posted. The documentation says: `By default an ImmutableMultiDict is returned from this function.`

Comment: To import: from flask import request

Answer (score 47):

As a newbie using Flask and Python myself, I think some of the other answers here take for granted that you have a good understanding of the fundamentals. In case you or other readers don't, I'll give more context

... `request.args` returns a "dictionary" object for you. The "dictionary" object is similar to other collection-type of objects in Python, in that it can store many elements in one single object.  Therefore the answer to your question

> And how many parameters `request.args.get()` takes.

It will take only one object, a "dictionary" type of object (as stated in the previous answers).  This "dictionary" object, however, can have as many elements as needed... (dictionaries have paired elements called Key, Value).

Other collection-type of objects besides "dictionaries", would be "tuple", and "list"... you can run a google search on those and "data structures" in order to learn other Python fundamentals. This answer is based Python; I don't have an idea if the same applies to other programming languages.

Answer (score 4):

`request.args` is a [MultiDict](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict) with the parsed contents of the query string. 
From the [documentation](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.get) of `get` method:

> **get**(*key, default=None, type=None*)
>
> Return the default value if the
>   requested data doesn’t exist. If type is provided and is a callable it
>   should convert the value, return it or raise a ValueError if that is
>   not possible.

Comment: Your links are broken.

Comment: Just need to change the version number in the url, like this http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.get

Answer (score 3):

It has some interesting behaviour in some cases that is good to be aware of:

```
from werkzeug.datastructures import MultiDict

d = MultiDict([("ex1", ""), ("ex2", None)])

d.get("ex1", "alternive")
# returns: ''

d.get("ex2", "alternative")
# returns no visible output of any kind
# It is returning literally None, so if you do:
d.get("ex2", "alternative") is None
# it returns: True

d.get("ex3", "alternative")
# returns: 'alternative'
```

Comment: This seems like exactly the behavior that one would expect - what are the interesting cases/behaviors you meant?

Comment: `MultiDict.get(key, default=None, type=None)` doesn't return the default value in the event that the stored value is "falsey". It looks for the key, and if it doesn't find the key in the `my_dict.keys()` list, then it returns the default value provided.

If you want a default value in the case that the key is either missing or "falsey", then you'd want something like:
`"alternative" if not d.get("ext1", False) else d.get("ext1")`

Comment: Wow, years back. My point, like blackfedora mentions above, was that I expected `d.get("ex1", "alternative")` and `d.get("ex2", "alternative")` both to return the alternative value, since their actual value is falsy.

Comment: use `d.get("ex1") or "alternative"` to get  "alternative"  if "ex1" not in d or is a falsy value. d.get("ex1", "alternative") means get "alternative" as default value if "ex1" not in d.