# Cannot upload file using multipart/form-data and Flask

Tags: forms, flask, sendfile

I'm not able to upload files through a simple form, using Flask.

I wrote below the simplified code of the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Debug</title>
</head>
<body>
   <form id="form_id" target="" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method = "POST">
     <input type="file" name="file">
     <button type="submit" name="action" value="add">Upload</button>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the Python Flask backend:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'JUST_FOR_TEST'

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def debugger():
    args = request.args.to_dict()
    if args != {}:
        return str(args)
    else:
        return render_template('debug.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

What should I fix for this form to work? Thank you all for your support.

Comment: the form works fine. what do you want to happen when the user clicks `submit`? do you want to save the file?

Comment: I would link to see a key "file" in "args" / request. But it seems that the form does not submit any "file" key in the request.

Comment: isn't `request.args` used for URL queries and `request.form` used for HTML forms? [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34671217/in-flask-what-is-request-args-and-how-is-it-used)

Comment: Thank you, AudioBaton. Changing request.args to request.form still returns an empty request:  "ImmutableMultiDict([])"

The problem seems to be in the html form. For some reason it does not append the file in the request. And doesn't metter what extension of file is attached.

Answer (score 2):

The clue provided by @AudioBaton solved the problem.

to access the file in request, one needs to pass

```
request.files['the_value_name_of_the_field_in_the_form']
```

instead of request.args or request.form.

Thank you, AudioBaton.

Comment: you are welcome, glad you figured it out!